# Various options in switch case

Tags: c++, c

I was trying to do a quiz in C. 5 answers, only one is correct. I'm using the switch. My doubt is on the case you have the number of the correct answer and the consequence of being correct. But on the other hand, I need to make the other 4 wrong. how can I select multiple answers? is it case 1,3,4,5? P.s. There's also the option of being invalid, and i need a  string for each case! pontos mean points and p1 is the answer.  Thank you

```
    switch (p1) {
    case 2 :
        correct answer
        pontos = pontos + 1;
        break;
    case 1, 3, 4, 5 :
        wrong answer
        pontos = pontos - 1;
    default :
        Invalid answer
        pontos = pontos - 1;
    }
```

Comment: Use the `default` case? Or just use an `if` - `else`

Comment: You can use `default:` for the wrong answers, but you don't really need a `switch` statement at all. A simple `if` . . . `else` will do.

Comment: Here is a manual: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

Answer (score 5):

You can stack up multiple `case` statements with the same body, like this:

```
switch (foo) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 5: {
        printf("Sorry, wrong answer.");
        break;
    }
    case 4: {
        printf("You got it right!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you could just use a `default` case to catch everything that's not right:

```
switch (foo) {
    case 4: {
        printf("You got it right!");
        break;
    }
    default: {
        printf("Sorry, wrong answer.");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or combine them: have 1/2/3/5 go to "wrong answer", and a default case saying "Pkease enter a number in the range 1-5".

Comment: but imagine it was 100 numbers, can't I use a range?

Comment: Since there's only one right answer, an `if` is better than a `switch` here.

Comment: @tadman I'm sure this is just an exercise to learn about `switch`, so an `if` statement wouldn't really help in that context. I expect that an upcoming assignment will be to build a test that can read an arbitrary number of questions and answers from a file.

Comment: @Caleb Absolutely, just offering an alternative. Code is always about the more minimal expression that gets the job done without being confusing.